# What is the rule of the dilation?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I was able to find the center of enlargement $(3,0)$ and the scale factor $-\frac{1}{2}$. I tried to write the rule for the dilation and I had $(x,y) \rightarrow (-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{9}{2}, \frac{1}{2}y)$. But seems so off. I can't figure out how to write the dilation rule.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In two dimensions, scaling around a point is
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x^\prime &= x_0 + s ( x - x_0 ) \\
y^\prime &= y_0 + s ( y - y_0 ) \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$
where $(x_0, y_0)$ is the center, $(x, y)$ is a point in the original coordinate system, $s$ is the scale factor, and $(x^\prime, y^\prime)$ is the point in the scaled coordinate system (image).  This should apply to each of your point pairs ($A$ and $A^\prime$, $B$ and $B^\prime$, and $C$ and $C^\prime$).

If the center is $C = (3,0)$, then $A - C = (3,-1)$ and $A^\prime - C = (-3,2)$; that does not seem like a scale factor of half to me; it looks to be an integer.

(In other words, you do have the correct center, but your scale factor is wrong.)

Comment: I plotted the points and find the ratios between the sides. All are one-half.

Comment: @harpey1111: The ratio $s$ is *new* / *old*, not *old* / *new*.

Comment: Oh... As far as I remember the image is the one with the Prime symbol. This means what scale factor did we use to get to the image (new) from pre-image (old). That's the ratio I used. if you're talking about general definition of ratios, it can be from old to new or new to old. But since the lesson is transformation, I think it should be old to new because as I said, the scale factor is to be used to get to the image (new).

Comment: So that's why I thought the coordinates are a bit odd. I just can't figure how to get the rule.

Comment: @harpey1111: Because $\text{new} = s \cdot \text{old}$, where $s$ is the scale factor (the same definition as in your problem statement), $s = \frac{\text{new}}{\text{old}}$. See? Why don't you try the center $(3,0)$ ($x_0=3$, $y_0=0$) and scale factor $s = -2$ in the formula in my answer, for each point pair, like $A$ and $A^\prime$?